# angular custom directive with ngModelChange

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I need to be able to format the value inside an input to thousands with comma. Before I was doing this way, see html below

```
<ion-input [ngModel]="myModel | number: '0-0'" (ngModelChange)="update($event)" format-number type="tel"></ion-input>
```

see ts

```
  update(value: string) {
    this.myModel = value.replace(/,/g, '');
  }
```

The problem with this is that for each input field , i need to add the update method in the component. What i want is to create a directive for that. I have created one as per below.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[format-number]', // Attribute selector
})
export class FormatNumbreDirective {

  numberPipe = new DecimalPipe('en-US');
  @Output() ngModelChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  constructor() {}

  @HostListener('input', ['$event']) oninput(event) {
    const element = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    let value = element.value.replace(/,/g, '');
    this.ngModelChange.emit(this.numberPipe.transform(value, '.0-0'));
  }
}
```

The html

```
<ion-input [(ngModel)]="myModel" format-number type="tel"></ion-input>
```

It works fine. But now i want to try it with ngModelChange. But i am getting an error 'Maximum call stack size exceeded.'

See directive below

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[format-number]', // Attribute selector
  host: {
    "(ngModelChange)": 'onInputChange($event)'
  }
})
export class FormatNumbreDirective {

  numberPipe = new DecimalPipe('en-US');
  @Output() ngModelChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  constructor() {
  }

  onInputChange($event) {
    let value = $event.replace(/,/g, '');
    this.ngModelChange.emit(this.numberPipe.transform(value, '.0-0'));
  }

}
```

See html

```
<ion-input [ngModel]="myModel" format-number type="tel"></ion-input>
```

Thanks for advise

Answer (score -1):

use this `[(ngModel)]="myModel"` it will trigger every time the value is changed